# SSO with Communities: Invalid portal id

Tags: community, single-sign-on, experience-cloud

I am implementing single sign on with my customer, **salesforce acting as service provider**.

We already tested the single sign on and it works for us with the Salesforce organization. We can log into the Salesforce organization without problems.

But we need to make single sign on work with a community portal.

**The assertions go well, but in "Setup" -> "Login History" we get an error: Invalid Portal Id**

The documentation says that in the SAML:Response the portal_id, organization_id and the siteUrl must be sent: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_saml_assertion_examples.htm&type=5 (assertions for Sites, assertions for portals)

**But we can't find where to get the portal id, we already tried with the Network Id and the Site Id, with these queries:** SELECT ID From Network ---- SELECT ID From Site (copying the ids that belong to our portal)
Neither of those two ids worked for us.

The documentation says that we will find the id in setup -> customer portal settings, but our organization does not have that. We already tried from Salesforce classic and that option does not appear in the "setup" either

Where can we get the portal_id for a community? Our community is configured in Setup -> All sites, we have the digital experience activated.

Comment: Did you try "Setup > Customize > Customer Portal > Customer Portal Settings"?

Comment: Yes @ŁukaszKojzar, I can't find that option in my organization, I also tried from Salesforce Classic and nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking with my colleagues from other projects, we came to the conclusion that the portal id is the same as the organization id.

So I tried putting the value of the organization_id in the portal_id and **it worked**.

Also, in the Identity Provider system, you must add `?sso=organization_id` to the end of your Salesforce login URL, if you don't already have it!